# Groovy column formatting with text wrapping

Tags: text, groovy, word-wrap

I am printing some output from a database to a text file.  I will basically print out four fixed-width columns.  The last column may need to wrap to the next line as the output from the db may be longer than the column-width.  Is there an easy way (or plugin) to do this in groovy?  Obviously if the column wraps, I don't want any further output from the other three columns to display until I'm done wrapping the last column.

This next part I'm more worried about.  Two of the other columns may also need to wrap - but can only wrap if that last column also needs to wrap.  Otherwise, I don't need to wrap those other two columns.  Output would be something like this:

> Col1 ..... Col2 no-wrap.......Col3 no-wrap.......Col4 no-wrap  
>   
>   Col1 ..... Col2 can..............Col3 can..............Col4 now needs 
>   .............. now wrap.............now wrap.............to wrap so wrap 
>   ......................................................................the others

Answer (score 0):

look at 
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Formatting+simple+tabular+text+data
for an example on how to format in columns with wrapping

Comment: Thanks bartoleo that was very helpful.  I took parts of this as well as from http://langref.org/groovy/strings/reversing-a-string/textwrap to get it to work.